# Как эффективно изменить значение в мапе?

Tags: c++

Как можно реализовать механизм изменения значения по ключу находящееся в векторе пар?
Хочется чтобы при добавлении очередного элемента по ключу я мог накапливать результат в одно из двух значений если первый элемент пары сопадает с новым элементом.

Для примера:

```
struct Data{
   size_t id;
   size_t hit;
};

map<string, vector<Data>> index;

index["a"].push_back({0, 1});
index["b"].push_back({0, 1});
index["c"].push_back({0, 1});
```

Т.е чтобы при добавлении новых ключа "a" и совпдании первого значении уже существующей пары с новой я накапливал результат во второй элемент тем самым исключая одинаковые элементы.

Я пробовал что-то в духе такого

```
size_t hitcount = 1;
size_t cur_id = 0;

if(index.count("a") != 0 && index["a"][cur_id].id == cur_id){
    hitcount = index["a"][cur_id].hit++;
    swap(index["a"][cur_id].hit, hitcount);
}else{
    index["a"].push_back({cur_id, 1}};
}
++cur_id;
```

Иногда это работает, но периодически в переменную hitcount попадает какой-то мусор и ключ просто не добавляется.

Есть ли более корректный и эффективный способ это сделать?

Comment: Может быть так попробуете `map<string, map<size_t, size_t> >`?

Comment: а этот код не работает случайно "многопоточненько"?

Answer (score 0):

> T& operator[]( const Key& key ); (1)   T& operator[]( Key&& key );
> (2)   (since C++11)

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a
> key equivalent to key, performing an insertion if such key does not
> already exist.

опрератор [] вставляет новый элемент, если он не был найден. ПО идее  новый элемент должен быть инициализированным значением (что будет означать нули в полях в данном случае), возможно баг реализации, так что вектор создет  не-иницализированные структуры?

Непонятно как гарантируется то, что в векторе достаточно места. Опреатор [] вектора не увеличивает его автоматически и можно выыйти за его границы,  это так  же может быть причиной сбоя.
Возможно следует использовать find() и вложенную карту вместо вектора,